# JGit RevWalk.parseTag does not release lock on pack file

Tags: java, git, jgit

I am using JGit API to display tags of a repository.

Following is the method that I have created to get tag from a Ref object.

```
private RevTag getTag(Git git, Ref ref) {
        RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk(git.getRepository());
        RevTag tag = null;
        ObjectId id = ref.getObjectId();

        try {
            tag = revWalk.parseTag(id);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        revWalk.release();
        return tag;
    }
```

This function successfully returns the RevTag object for the tag, but it locks certain pack file in the .git/objects directory and does not release the lock. If I try to delete the repository from windows explorer I get an error saying that the resource is being used. If I kill the java process which calls this method, I can delete the repository without any errors.

Am I doing something wrong to get the tag?

Comment: I tried to debug/profile this, but the files were correctly closed for me with the repository.close() call. Can you provide more of your code so that the full flow is visible? Ideally a cut down minimal set of steps which show the problem for you!

Answer (score 0):

Very likely the files are locked because the repository was not closed. Does your code call `Repository#close()` before you try to delete the repository?

Here goes an example that uses a RevWalk to parse a tag without leaking resources:

```
@Rule
public final TemporaryFolder tempFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

@Test
public void testRevWalkDoesNotLeakResources() throws Exception {
  Git git = Git.init().setDirectory( tempFolder.getRoot() ).call();
  git.commit().setMessage( "First commit" ).call();
  git.tag().setName( "First-Tag" ).call();
  Ref tagRef = git.getRepository().getRef( "refs/tags/First-Tag" );
  RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk( git.getRepository() );
  RevTag tag = revWalk.parseTag( tagRef.getObjectId() );
  revWalk.release();
  git.getRepository().close();

  tempFolder.delete();

  assertNotNull( tag );
  assertFalse( tempFolder.getRoot().exists() );
}
```

Comment: Yes. I have tried using both Repository#close() and Git#close() before deleting the repository. It gives same error with or without calling these methods.

Comment: I have put together a test snippet in the answer above that creates a repository with a tag, reads the tag and then closes the repository. The test then deletes the repository directory. The code runs successfully with the latest JGit on Windows.

Can you confirm that this code also runs in your environment? If not, what version of JGit do you use?